# using expand=true in Solr SynonymFilterFactory?

Tags: solr

Solr doc explains the role of expand=true in SynonymFilterFactory as the followings:

```
a synonym will be expanded to all equivalent synonyms. 
If it is false, all equivalent synonyms will be reduced to the first in the list.
```

I am wondering what it means exactly? If someone could elaborate on what it does, it will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Solr [SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) documentation on the Solr Wiki:

```
 # If expand==true, "ipod, i-pod, i pod" is equivalent to the explicit mapping:
 ipod, i-pod, i pod => ipod, i-pod, i pod

 # If expand==false, "ipod, i-pod, i pod" is equivalent to the explicit mapping:
 ipod, i-pod, i pod => ipod
```

Since Solr SynonymFilterFactory is now deprecated, the SynonymGraphFilterFactory class is now used. This answer still holds true for SynonymGraphFilterFactory.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what the first statement means? Would you explain in layman's terms what it means?

Comment: It means that if you set the expand="true" option. Then in the 1st case listed above, anytime your field contains ipod, i-pod or i pod as terms, it will replace that one one term with all three in the index.

Comment: Simple explanation , the current solr documentation doesn't explain this clearly . Wondering why vague explanations are given in books and docs . The whole purpose of any book or documentation should be such that anybody can understand